# Mongo : check locked documents

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to check number of locked documents in a Mongo collection. 
I know I can use :

```
db.collection.stats()
```

to check status of a collection. However, I want to know number of locked documents in a collection and list all such documents that might still be locked.

Is there a built-in Mongo function to do so?

Thanks,
Ravish

Comment: What do you mean by "locked"? MongoDB doesn't have document level locking granularity.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky , by locked I mean, the documents that might still be locked due to any failed transaction. For example, while while updating documents in a transaction, mongo locks all the documents and in case of failed update, rollback the transaction and unlock all the locked documents. I suspect some of my documents are still locked after a failed transaction, so, wanted to check if there is a way to check all such locked document...

Comment: MongoDB does not have transactions nor are there rollbacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB does not have multi-document transactions like RDBMS.

If may help you to read this item from MongoDB FAQ:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-do-transactions-and-locking-in-mongodb

It is therefore absolutely not possible that some of your documents "are still locked after a failed transaction."